# Open two existing word files from excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Hi I'm trying to write code to use excel to work with two existing word documents but I keep getting OLE errors. This is just the start but it keeps crashing. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub BoQtoWord()
Dim Word As Object
Dim WordDoc As Object
Dim WordDoc1 As Object
Dim StdSpec As String
Dim NewSpec As String

StdSpec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(StdSpec)
Sheet1.Range ("A1").Value = StdSpec
NewSpec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set WordDoc1 = Word.Documents.Open(NewSpec)
Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = NewSpec

End Sub
```

Comment: It works better now I have specified word files in the GetOpenFilename but still struggles after that with OLE errors.

Comment: I admit I'm not familiar with `GetOpenFilename()`, but you're calling it *before* you open a word document. Wouldn't that set `StdSpec` to whatever the open file name is at that time? What if you move `StdSpec = ...` to the line after you open the Word doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to works fine on my end, albeit a bit slow, at least as far as writing the file paths to cells A1 and A2 is concerned. Beyond that we'd need to see more of your code.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish with the Word objects the OLE problems might stem from conflicts in your references, make sure you check what libraries you are referencing (Tools/References...) for any possible conflict.

Another possible conflict might be the use of the word "Word" as your variable name for the object. Word is also a key name when using the Microsoft Word library, try using a different name see if that helps at all.

Speaking of which, by adding the Microsoft Word library to your references you can skip the step to create the word object, you can directly create a word.document object instead, like this:

```
Sub BoQtoWord()
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordDoc1 As Word.Document
Dim StdSpec As String
Dim NewSpec As String

'Get first doc
StdSpec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set WordDoc = Documents.Open(StdSpec)
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = StdSpec

'Get second doc
NewSpec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set WordDoc1 = Documents.Open(NewSpec)
Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = NewSpec

'Do something with the documents opened

End Sub
```

Maybe that would solve your OLE problems.

Hope this points you in the right direction, if anything, a bit more information might help narrow down the issue!

Comment: Hi AlSkylark. I hadn't added the MS Word object library as you say by doing this it now works. The rest of the code is work in progress but will involve copying text from bookmarks in one word file to another if a condition is met in the excel worksheets. Thanks for your help