# VBA copy text from two word documents based on excel condition

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a sub from excel that will open two existing word files one with standard text and another blank. These word documents and the excel workbook have the same string values as the bookmarks. If the corresponding cells adjacent to the excel bookmark are not blank I want to copy the standard text across to the other document. It just keeps crashing my excel, any ideas?

```
Sub BoQtoWord()
'Proof of concept to copy text from standard word doc to new word doc at same bookmark if condition met in excel workbook

Dim StdDoc As Word.Document
Dim NewDoc As Word.Document
Dim StdSpec As String
Dim NewSpec As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim iRow As Integer
iRow = 6
Dim Bkm As String


'Get first doc
StdSpec = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose standard spec to open", _
FileFilter:="Word Files *.doc* (*.doc*),")
Set StdDoc = Documents.Open(StdSpec)

'Get second doc
NewSpec = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose new spec to open", _
FileFilter:="Word Files *.doc* (*.doc*),")
Set NewDoc = Documents.Open(NewSpec)


'Loop through worksheet in workbook and copy data from standard doc to new doc at same bookmark if values populated in column 4 and 7.

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

    For iRow = 6 To 200
        Bkm = Cells(iRow, 9).Value
            If Cells(iRow, 9) <> "" And Cells(iRow, 4) <> "" Then

            Documents(StdDoc).Activate
            Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Bkm"
            Selection.Copy

            Documents(NewDoc).Activate
            Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Bkm"
            Selection.Paste

        End If
        iRow = iRow + 1

    Next iRow

Next



End Sub
```

Comment: Did you add in the Microsoft Word Object Library? You should also be avoiding activate, and instead use explicit references, at a guess it is getting confused as to what it should be looking at inside your loop, since you are bouncing between two word docs and a spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Warcupine yes I imported the Word 16.0 Object Libary

Comment: You haven't created a Word Application instance to use in your automation.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. I thought by using the word object library I didn't need to do this. Can you suggest an edit?

Comment: See here for example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310258/pasting-from-excel-into-a-word-document?rq=1  Adding the Word library reference allows your Excel-hosted VBA to recognise Word VBA-specific methods, etc, but you still need to create an instance of the Word application to "host" your Word documents etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub BoQtoWord()

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim StdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim NewDoc As Word.Document
    Dim StdSpec As String
    Dim NewSpec As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim iRow As Integer
    iRow = 6
    Dim Bkm As String

    Set wdApp = New Word.Application '<<<  create a Word application object

    wdApp.Visible = True '<<<< EDIT - added so you can see any errors 

    StdSpec = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose standard spec to open", _
                                          FileFilter:="Word Files *.doc* (*.doc*),")

    Set StdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(StdSpec) '<< you need to call Documents.Open on the word app..

    NewSpec = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose new spec to open", _
                                          FileFilter:="Word Files *.doc* (*.doc*),")

    Set NewDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(NewSpec)

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For iRow = 6 To 200
            'Need to use ws here to make sure you're
            '  referencing the correct sheet...
            Bkm = ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value
            If ws.Cells(iRow, 9) <> "" And ws.Cells(iRow, 4) <> "" Then
                'no need for any selection to copy/paste
                StdDoc.Bookmarks(Bkm).Range.Copy
                NewDoc.Bookmarks(Bkm).Range.Paste
            End If
        Next iRow
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the lesson on VBA objects. I tried the code but it keeps crashing excel due to OLE errors. Is my goal just a bit too ambitious to do with VBA?

Comment: This should be totally do-able with VBA. Are you getting a specific error?  If Yes, then what is it and on which line(s)?

Comment: So I've tried a few things and still get the MS excel is waiting another application to perform a OLE action error. I replaced the getopenfilename with a hard coded file reference and made simplified new word and excel documents. With getopenfilename method the browser opens twice to select the files but then nothing happens. It is not even opening word anymore. Don't get as far as the For Each loop. I am doing this on a work Laptop and there are some locked corporate template projects in word developer which could be a reason?

Comment: See my edit above to set Word to be visible, so you can see if there are any errors.  Check Task Manager to see if you have any hidden instances of Word you need to close out.

Comment: So a version I had of the above code that opened the word files and just pasted the path to excel used to work but is no longer working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59329032/open-two-existing-word-files-from-excel So it seems like my word app has gone kaput! How do I reset it?

Comment: Did you check to see if you had hidden word instances running?  If you can launch Word manually then it's more likely a problem with your code than with Word itself

Comment: Thank you so much Tim making the wdApp visible has done the trick. I was shutting down via task manager before but that didn't do it. If you're ever in Skipton I owe you a drink!

Comment: Funny that used to be almost my neighbourhood (Bradford) but it's been a while now...  Good to hear you got it sorted out.